# Proving a limit by Cauchy definition

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

for $a>1$:

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to \infty } \frac{{{a^x}}}{x} = \infty $$

So, by the definition of Cauchy for limits, for any $M>0$ I need to find a $D>0$ such that:
$x>D$ implies $\frac{{{a^x}}}{x} > M$.

I thought maybe defining ${a^x} = {e^y}$ and tried developing it, but without success. 
What do you suggest?

Comment: What's "Cauchy limits", again?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%28%CE%B5,_%CE%B4%29-definition_of_limit

Comment: Oh, that's **the** usual definition of limit...ok.

Comment: I think it's easy to prove the funciton is monotonically increasing, but the demand is proving it by the delta-epsilon limit definition.

Comment: Or is it ok using this property of monotony here?

Comment: Do you already know some other basic limits? Say, $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac x{\log x}=\infty\;?$$

Comment: I think We've encountered in class with this function or something similar to that.

Comment: Beautiful profile picture by the way.

Comment: Did you mean $\lim\limits_{x\to\color{red}{+}\infty}\dfrac{a^x}x=\color{red}{+}\infty$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $$\frac{a^{n+1}/(n+1)}{a^n/n}=\frac{n}{n+1}a.$$
Since the ratio on the right goes to 1, if you pick any $b\in(1,a)$ then the whole expression is $>b$ for $n$ large enough. So now you can compare $a^n/n$ with $b^n$, which is much easier to handle.

I am leaving the details to you. These include, of course, handling non-integral $x$ by comparing with a nearby integer $n$.

Comment: Let me interpret your answer: $f(x+1)/f(x) \ge b$.  
Therefore, it's sufficient taking the limit of ${b^n}$?

Comment: Basically, yes, at least when the limit is $\infty$. At least for integers $x$. You prove by induction that $f(n+k)\ge f(n)b^k$, and take it from there. For non-integers $x$, let $n=\lfloor x\rfloor$, and use $a^x\ge a^n$ and $x<n+1$ to get an estimate for $a^x$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $a^x=\exp(x\ln a)\ge 1+x\ln a+\frac12(x\ln a)^2$. Make sure you mention where you use $a>1$.

Alternative expression of the same idea: If $2\le n\le x<n+1$ then
\begin{align}
\frac{a^x}x>\frac{(1+(a-1))^n}{n+1}\ge\frac{1+n(a-1)+\frac{n(n-1)}2(a-1)^2}{n+1}.
\end{align}

I realise that I am already helping too much here.

Comment: that's a nice approach, but can you explain the inequality please?

Comment: The inequality comes from either the Taylor series of the exponential function, or just Taylor's formula with remainder. But I suspect that you haven't learned about those, which is why I wrote my answer the way I did.

Comment: Well, I thought one would need a definition for $a^x$ before proving anything about it ;)  But it's a good point.