# Show that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{a^x}{x}=\infty$ as $x\rightarrow$ $\infty$ for $a>1$

Tags: calculus, limits

Using Cauchy and Heine (Taylor expansion, L'Hospital rule, etc... is not allowed), prove that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{a^x}{x}=\infty$ as $x$ approaches $\infty$ for $a>1$.

Iv'e seen this - [Proving a limit by Cauchy definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/606423/proving-a-limit-by-cauchy-definition), but didn't understand how I can evaluate.

Please help, thank you!

Comment: How do you define $a^x$?

Comment: Is is possible to write $a^x=e^{x ln(a)}$. How does it help me to advance?

Comment: $a^x>x^2$ for large values of x and $a>1$

Comment: And how do you show that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $b=a-1>0$. For each natural $n>3$, if $n\leq x<n+1$, you have
$$\begin{align}
\frac{a^x}x&>\frac{a^n}{n+1}\\
&=\frac{(1+b)^n}{n+1}\\
&\geq\frac{1+bn+\frac{n^2-n}2b^2}{2n-2}\\
&>\frac{b^2}4n
\end{align}
$$

*Note:* The condition $n>3$ has the only reason of that we can "transform" the denominator $n+1$ into $2n-2$ in order to simplify the factor $(n-1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Choose an $x$-value. Calculate the value of the fraction. Now double your $x$-value. The denominator doubles in value (of course) but the value of the numerator gets *squared*. If the numerator was larger than $2$ in the first place, this means the value of the fraction got  larger.

Now the value of the numerator is larger than $4$, so the sext time you double your $x$-value the fraction will be increased to at least twice of what it was. At the next doubling of $x$, it will be increased by a factor of at least $8$. And so on.

Now you just need to prove that there is an $x$ with $a^x \geq 2$.